# Pagination does't work for my Django rest framework project and I'm using generic-views

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have tried many options, but pagination still doesn't work. I'm using generic-views and code like this:

```
class ListFood(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Food.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FoodSerializer

    def list(self,request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = FoodSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and in `settings.py`, I have written this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS':'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20
}
```

I have tried to modify particular aspects of the pagination style, such as:

```
class StandardResultsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 100
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    max_page_size = 1000

class ListFood(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = Food.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FoodSerializer
    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination

    def list(self,request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = FoodSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

but it still didn't work.

My `urls.py` is:

```
app_name = "lab"
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^food/$', ListFood.as_view(), name="listfood"),
    ]
```

There is no error message, but when I request the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/food/?page=1` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/food/?page=2`

it's still not paginated. Django gives me 2000 pieces of data in JSON.

Comment: Why are you overriding `list()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Original `list` implementation paginates response:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Your class overrides `list` with custom implementation, that is why it does not return paginated response. Just don't override `list`.

Comment: thanks, I know what mistake I have made.

thanks again.